# VB adding coefficients to table.compute

Tags: vb.net, function, math

I've created a software so that text box inputs are calculated through a table but when a coefficient is added, such as "2X" the table cannot compute it and doesn't output the desired solution to the function. I've tried different methods but I need a way so that the table can understand a coefficient. below shows what I have already:

```
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim v As Integer
        n = txtNeg.Text
        v = txtPos.Text
        Dim table = New DataTable()
        For x As Integer = n To v Step 1
            Dim y = table.Compute(txtY.Text.Replace("x", x).Replace("X", x).Replace("s", (Math.Sin(x / 57.3))).Replace("S", (Math.Sin(x / 57.3))).Replace("c", (Math.Cos(x / 57.3))).Replace("C", (Math.Cos(x / 57.3))).Replace("x2", x * x).Replace("X2", x * x).Replace("L", Math.Abs(Math.Log(x))).Replace("l", Math.Abs(Math.Log(x))).Replace("e", Math.Exp(x)), Nothing)

            Chart1.Series("plot1").Points.AddXY(x, y)
```

I can make it so that it pre-exists in the code, for example:

```
If txtY.Text = "2x" Then y = x * 2
If txtY.Text = "3x" Then y = x * 3
```

etc, but i would like it so that it understands the coefficient without it needing to be pre-existing if anyone knows how

Comment: @TimSchmelter usually then i input a function such as " x + 5 " this is computed through the table and the output is a graph of " x + 5 " but as soon as i enter " 2x + 5 ", the 2 isn't multiplied by the x but instead acts like a prefix, an output of " 1, 2, 3" becomes "21, 22, 23" and doesnt act as a coefficient. my result needs to be " 2 * x + 5 ". i hope that explains it a little

Comment: You need to turn on Option Strict for this project and all your projects. Since you appear to be using `Replace(String, String)` a liberal sprinkling of `.ToString` on the second parameter will help. There is no overload of `Replace` that takes a number.

Comment: @Mary thank you! is there not a way for me to use a statement such as ```if txtY.text = integer & "x" then y = integer * x``` possibly?

Comment: This looks interesting
https://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/calculator-net-calculator-that-evaluates-math-expressions
Also check out the Expression class in .net
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-5.0